# Using of @Html.TextArea in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to use `@Html.TextArea()` instead of `@Html.EditorFor()` but I am getting this error

> cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type.

Model

```
public class ProductFeature
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} boş geçilemez")]
    [DisplayName("Ürün Özellik Adı")]
    public string ProductFeatureName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} boş geçilemez")]
    [DisplayName("Ürün Özellik Değeri")]
    public string ProductFeatureValue { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

View

```
// Works
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductFeatureName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

// Throws error
@Html.TextArea(model => model.ProductFeatureName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: Where is the code that you use for `TextArea()`? And what does 99% of this code have to do with your question?

Comment: That's the code for `EditorFor()` You question is about `TextArea()` - what code did you try that gave that error?

Comment: Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductFeatureName, new { htmlAttributes = new { class = "form-control" } })

  Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductFeatureValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { class = "form-control" } })

I want to use Html.TextArea instead of Html.EditorFor. Cannot i ?

Comment: Of course you can. Edit you code with the code you tried and we will correct it for you

Comment: i did try like this "Html.TextArea(model => model.ProductFeatureName, new { htmlAttributes = new { class = "form-control" } })" but red line appeared it's below and this error "cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use an expression, then you need to use the strong typed `xxxFor()` methods

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ProductFeatureValue, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

alternatively your can use

```
@Html.TextArea("ProductFeatureValue", new { @class = "form-control" } )
```

or you could add the `DataTypeAttribute` to you property

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string ProductFeatureName { get; set; }
```

and use `EditorFor()` which will then generate a `<textarea>`